# Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

Como posso fazer com que uma ListView monte os itens da seguinte forma:

Quando tiver apenas um item ele ocupe a tela inteira, se tiver dois divida em 50% o tamanho da tela entre os itens e assim por diante...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"  
   android:layout_height="match_parent"  
   android:orientation="vertical"
   tools:context=".ListViewActivity" >  

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaromaneiosview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@color/Black"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    tools:listitem="@layout/cre_004_listaromaneios_adpter" >

</ListView>
```

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textoListView"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:textSize="@dimen/titulo"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/selecionaRomaneio"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:onClick="actionListner"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
```

Comment: Tente colocar a altura deles como fill_parent.

Comment: já tentei não deu certo, ele não ficou na tela cheia..

Comment: Qual o layout que vc ta usando?

Comment: RelativeLayout e LinearLayout para o item da lista

Comment: A ListView precisa ficar como fill_parent e o elemento pai do Adapter que o TextView e ImageButton estão precisa estar como fill_parent também. Tenta assim acredito que deve funcionar!

Comment: Acho que esse comportamento não é possível, talvez terá que fazer "na mão" usando um `LinearLayout` e usando o `weight` e `weightSum` dos filhos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView`, do ponto de vista dos filhos, tem altura infinita, não faz sentido um `match_parent`. O que você precisa é de um `LinearLayout` (não se esqueça do `orientation="vertical"`) e vai adicionando os filhos com `layout_height="0dp"` e `layout_weight="1"` (o valor não importa, desde que seja o mesmo para todos os itens). Por questões de performance, coloque também o `weightSum` no `LinearLayout` como a soma dos pesos (weight) dos filhos. É possível fazer isso em tempo de execução também com `setWeightSum()`.

Comment: obrigado vou testar !!